# $\lim_{x \to \infty} [(x^5+7x^4+2)^a-x]=b$ and $b\not=0$. What is the value of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x \to \infty} [(x^5+7x^4+2)^a-x]=b$ and $b\not=0$.

What is the value of $a$ and $b$?

Thanks for ahead:)

Comment: Observe $(x^5+7x^4+2)^a-x]\approx x^{5a}-x$ as $x\longrightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Could you say more...

Comment: If $a>\frac{1}{5}$ then $x^{5a}-x$ increases without bound as $x\longrightarrow \infty$. On the other hand, if $a<\frac{1}{5}$ then $x^{5a}<x$ and $x^{5a}-x\longrightarrow -\infty$ as $x\longrightarrow \infty$. Then it should be $a=\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: @MarioG  Thanks. I still want to know why $(x^5+7x^4+2)^a =x^{5a}$ holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$(x^5+7x^4+2)^a\sim_\infty x^{5a}$$
so we should impose $5a=1$ since otherwise the limit isn't finite. So let $\boxed{a=\frac 15}$ then
$$(x^5+7x^4+2)^{1/5}-x=x\left(1+\frac7x+\frac2{x^5}\right)^{1/5}-x\sim_\infty \boxed{\frac7{5}=b}$$

Comment: Why is $b=\frac{7}{5}$? $x^{1/5}-x$ goes to $-\infty$ ...

Comment: I used the Taylor formula:
$$(1+x)^{\alpha}\sim_0 1+\alpha x$$

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane: Thanks for your help. Why $$(x^5+7x^4+2)^a\sim_\infty x^{5a}$$ holds?

Comment: We neglect the terms $x^4$ and $2$ and more basically since we have
$$(x^5+7x^4+2)^a=x^a\left(1+\frac7x+\frac2{x^5}\right)^a$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac7x+\frac2{x^5}\right)^a=1$$

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane: I see. Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome.@Paul